# Sort List by first term in case and select cases which certain number in the first term

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list:

```
 list = {{1,3.4},{2,6.7},{3,0},{1,2},{2,8.6},{3,7.9},{1,0},{2,7.8},{3,5}};
```

I will like to sort the list by the first term in the order they are presented on the list like the following:

```
 {{1,3.4},{1,2},{1,0},{2,6.7},{2,8.6},{2,7.8},{3,0},{3,7.9},{3,5}}.
```

Finally I will like to make three different list which select the cases starting with certain number as:

```
list1 = {{1,3.4},{1,2},{1,0}}
list2 = {{2,6.7},{2,8.6},{2,7.8}}
list3 = {{3,0},{3,7.9},{3,5}}
```

Comment: Look up `GatherBy[]`.

Comment: Thanks! It helped for the fist part. Now, how can I create a list with only the cases that start for example by 1?

Comment: Why doesn't `GatherBy[data, First]` not solve your problem completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 3.4}, {2, 6.7}, {3, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 8.6}, {3, 7.9}, {1, 0}, {2, 7.8}, {3, 5}}

{list1, list2, list3} = GatherBy[list, First];
```

The more general way is

```
res = GatherBy[list, First];
```

and then get a particular part with f.e.

```
res[[2]]
```

> {{2, 6.7}, {2, 8.6}, {2, 7.8}}

Comment: Thanks! Is there a more general way? I have from 1 to 200. I can write list1, list2,...list200 but it would take long.

Comment: see update -------